# Call methods inside a class from a series of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

From a series of string, I am trying to call methods inside a class.
Unfortunately, The method is not called properly because it needs the `self` to indicate it is internal to the class.  How can I fix that logic?

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def apply(self):
        rules = [{'action': 'replace'}, {'action': 'split'}, {'action': 'remove'}]
        return [eval('_perform_' + r['action'])() for r in rules
              if r['action'] in ['replace', 'split', 'remove']]

    def _perform_replace(self):
        print("performing replace")

    def _perform_split(self):
        print("performing split")

    def _perform_remove(self):
        print("performing remove") 

SomeClass().apply()
```

This throws following exception:

> NameError: name '_perform_replace' is not defined

Comment: If you want to access `staticmethods` you have to use a `decorater` to define the class as a static member function. Then you call it like `SomeClass.apply()` without the `()`. Furthermore if you are trying to split/escape strings in python, there are much easier ways than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I know there are simple methods but here my `rules` list is actually a json file with several domain-specific rules. - The replace/split/remove are more involved and require interactions with pandas data frames. I did not explain that to focus on the core of my problem.

Comment: You can access the methods like attributes of the object using getattr. So from inside your apply method you could use `getattr(self, '_perform_' + r['action'])()`

Comment: @antonagestam thanks, is this safer than the option provided by the accepted answer?

Comment: @Michael The current accepted answer does exactly that only wraps it in a static method. I would say there's no difference in safety since both are using `getattr`. It's always a good idea to avoid using eval. :)

Comment: @Michael I think this is a really good example of how functions are first class citizens in Python. Methods are just functions that are called with their instance as first argument. And methods are attributes of the class/instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `self` to invoke the instance methods. So, change your `apply` function to

```
  def apply(self):
        rules = [{'action': 'replace'}, {'action': 'split'}, {'action': 'remove'}]
        return [eval('self._perform_' + r['action'])() for r in rules
              if r['action'] in ['replace', 'split', 'remove']]
```

**Note**: Using `eval` is a bad practice. You can find the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

You can make use of `getattr` instead.

**For example**(this example is just to illustrate how `getattr` is working)

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def apply(self):
        method_to_be_called = "_perform_replace"
        SomeClass.method_caller(method_to_be_called)(self)
        # Invoke like this if you want your function to accept args.
        # SomeClass.method_caller(method_to_be_called, args1, args2,...)(self)

    def _perform_replace(self):
        print("performing replace")

    def _perform_split(self):
        print("performing split")

    def _perform_remove(self):
        print("performing remove")

    @staticmethod
    def method_caller(name_, *args, **kwargs):
        def caller(obj):
            return getattr(obj, name_)(*args, **kwargs)

        return caller
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could you propose an alternative to `eval` that will be less risky for my example?

Comment: thanks, if `apply` needs to pass parameters to the `_perform` methods - those parameters will be passed like so? `SomeClass.method_caller(method_to_be_called)(self, a, b)`

Comment: I accepted your answer as it provides a direct fit in my current logic but also provide a better solution! Thanks for this great support.

Comment: @Michael Correction: If `apply` needs to pass parameters to the `_perform` methods - those parameters should be passed like `SomeClass.method_caller(method_to_be_called, a, b)(self)` not `SomeClass.method_caller(method_to_be_called)(self, a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a little involved, but if you want to call functions based on some logic, you can just use the function like a pointer. Here is an example:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def apply():
        rules = [{'action':SomeClass.test()}]
        return rules[0]['action']

    @staticmethod
    def test():
        print("test")


SomeClass.apply()
>test
```

I'm not sure if you are familiar with `staticmethods` but if your functions can live at their own, you can `decorate` your functions to be static to call them from anywhere.